Add extra.label for two or more same authors in same year
Using \usepackage{natbib} and \bibliographystyle{chicago}, how can I get an extra.label for references of the same year and the same first authors. I am using this bst file.
By default the label is only added when the two references have the exact same authors. However, I need it to work for: Author, A., B. Bauther, C., Cauther (2024) and Author, A., B. Bauther, D., Dauther (2024), which would then be cited in-text as Author et al. (2024a) and Author et al. (2024b). The letters also need to appear in the reference list.
It seems like it all happens in FUNCTION {forward.pass} at the end of the bst file but I cannot make it work.
(I need to stay in the natbib-chicago framework because I have already adapted the style file in different other ways to my needs.)
